# Kotlin Flow Catch Operator

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I am trying to understand catch implementation for flow api. But I am confused about how the api checks equality of exceptions in `Flow.catchImpl`.

This is the code from coroutines library. What I don't understand is `RECOVER_STACK_TRACES` parameter.

Depending on it; `internal actual inline fun <E : Throwable> unwrap(exception: E): E` will return different outputs and the behavior of `internal suspend fun <T> Flow<T>.catchImpl(collector: FlowCollector<T>): Throwable?` will be different. What am I missing?

```
// Return exception from upstream or null
internal suspend fun <T> Flow<T>.catchImpl(
    collector: FlowCollector<T>
): Throwable? {
    var fromDownstream: Throwable? = null
    try {
        collect {
            try {
                collector.emit(it)
            } catch (e: Throwable) {
                fromDownstream = e
                throw e
            }
        }
    } catch (e: Throwable) {
        /*
         * First check ensures that we catch an original exception, not one rethrown by an operator.
         * Seconds check ignores cancellation causes, they cannot be caught.
         */
        if (e.isSameExceptionAs(fromDownstream) || e.isCancellationCause(coroutineContext)) {
            throw e // Rethrow exceptions from downstream and cancellation causes
        } else {
            return e // not from downstream
        }
    }
    return null
}

private fun Throwable.isCancellationCause(coroutineContext: CoroutineContext): Boolean {
    val job = coroutineContext[Job]
    if (job == null || !job.isCancelled) return false
    return isSameExceptionAs(job.getCancellationException())
}

private fun Throwable.isSameExceptionAs(other: Throwable?): Boolean =
    other != null && unwrap(other) == unwrap(this)

**@Suppress("NOTHING_TO_INLINE") // Inline for better R8 optimizations
internal actual inline fun <E : Throwable> unwrap(exception: E): E =
    if (!RECOVER_STACK_TRACES) exception else unwrapImpl(exception)

internal fun <E : Throwable> unwrapImpl(exception: E): E {
    val cause = exception.cause
    // Fast-path to avoid array cloning
    if (cause == null || cause.javaClass != exception.javaClass) {
        return exception
    }
    // Slow path looks for artificial frames in a stack-trace
    if (exception.stackTrace.any { it.isArtificial() }) {
        @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
        return cause as E
    } else {
        return exception
    }
}**
```